# Creating CloudWatch alarm based on AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I am creating an alarm based on AMI in cloudwatch. We have several AMIs. Some AMIs are missing in the list (see pics). Any suggestion, how to get missing AMIs in this view.

create alarm screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You need to [enable detailed monitoring](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-cloudwatch-new.html) for these instances if you want them to appear in the list.

Answer (score -1):

Because you are trying to use an aggregate statistic you must use detailed monitoring or the AMIs will not appear

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/US_SingleMetricPerAMI.html

Down voters please read the docs, surprising but true